# How do I collect data for simple self-survey

Tags: survey, scales

I am on a self-experiment quest to solve some health related problems I have, and I want to create a self-survey that I take every day.  What's the best way to codify the survey so I can later analyze the data?  I am not a statistics guru, as you can tell, so I'm probably asking a pretty basic question here.  For the survey itself, I plan to use a Google Docs Form.

To give you some examples of the data I'd like to track, here are some example questions:

- Did I consume dairy?
- What was my stress level?
- How was my mood?
- How many hours of sunlight did I receive?
- Did I play with my children today?

And so on..

My question is, how can I limit my own bias and quantify these things in a way that will be most useful?

Comment: I think you might be interested in existing (and validated) instruments; e.g., the [PROQOLID](http://www.proqolid.org/) database which surveys a lot of questionnaires targeting health-related quality of life and patient reported outcomes. If no questionnaire really suits your needs, you can still get an idea of what domains to assess and how to devise specific items, depending on your very own interests. As for coding practice, there are a lot of possibilities, ranging from yes/no or Likert-type items, visual analog scale (VAS), preference scaling, etc.

Comment: (Con't) Coding is another issue, but most probably you will end up with integer values (yes=1, no=0; totally disagree=0 -- totally agree=4; 0-10 for a VAS) that can be analyzed separately or aggregated into composite scores. Any decent textbook on scale construction will provide some guidelines on questionnaire development and useful recommendations on item construction and analysis.